# Getting a git error when trying to install mysql with brew

Tags: mysql, git, homebrew

I'm installing mysql on OS Mojave with brew. I got this error:

```
Stack:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2   -[DVTExtension valueForKey:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3   _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  4   _IDEInitializePlugIns (in IDEFoundation)
  5   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
  6   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  7  0x0000000103785202 (in xcodebuild)
  8   start (in libdyld.dylib)

sh: line 1: 10700 Abort trap: 6           
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk macosx -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH
Error: Failure while executing; `git config --local --replace-all homebrew.private true` exited with 72.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: run `brew install git` first

Comment: Or the Xcode command line tools (which are probably going to be required anyway): `xcode-select --install`